# Why Do we need a right-continuous filtration with $\mathcal{F}_0$ containing all P-null sets?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-differential-equations, filtrations

When we consider a Stochastic Differential Equation we let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\ge 0},P )$ be a complete probability space with a filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ satisfying the usual conditions, i.e. it is right continuous and $\mathcal F_0$ contains all $P$-null sets.

Why are these "usual" conditions important ?
What if we omit them ?

Answer (score 1):

In Karatzas-Shreve 2.7 "Brownian filtrations" they go over the motivation for augmenting by null-sets and the right continuity. See also [Properties of Feller Processes](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/19/properties-of-feller-processes/#scn_fpp_thm4).

Here are some reasons:

- For every strong-Markov/Feller process, its augmented filtration is *right-continuous* $$\mathcal{F}_{t}=\bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal{F}_{t}.$$

eg. see the above references or [Proof that augmented filtration is right continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982140/proof-that-augmented-filtration-is-right-continuous).

- One implication of right-continuity is Blumenthal’s zero-one law. Consider, for example, a standard Brownian motion B. It can be shown $B_t$ hits zero infinitely often for t in any neighborhood of 0, with probability one. Events such as this are $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable for each $t>0$ and, therefore, $\mathcal{F}_{0+}$ measurable.
- Also, Brownian motion needs to be modified at a measure zero set to even have continuity by the Kolmogorov continuity theorem.
- The hitting time of **open sets** is also sensitive to right-continuity eg. see[When is the hitting time of an open set a stopping time?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209446/when-is-the-hitting-time-of-an-open-set-a-stopping-time).
- from [Right-continuity of filtrations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167879/right-continuity-of-filtrations): Suppose that $X \in L^1$ is a random variable and $(D_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a right-continuous filtration. Then $$\lim_{s \downarrow t} \mathbb{E}(X \mid D_s) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid D_t).$$